# Can't get FragmentManager to respond correctly to back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on an activity which shows a couple different fragments.

Let's say Activity A shows fragments B C and D in that order. When I press the back button on D, I would like C to be shown, C goes to B, etc. However, whenever I press the back button Activity A acts as if the back button was pressed on it and exits the activity.

Here's what my transactions look like, this is all done in Activity A...

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, FragmentB.newInstance(Types.Mine))
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

I then for the following fragments, I perform:

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, FragmentC.newInstance(Types.OXY))
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Changing the add to replace. I've done this with a couple different configurations but can't seem to get the correct behavior. Any suggestions??

Edit: I've looked at the getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() after every transaction, and it seems they're being added correctly because the count keeps going up...

Comment: Do you override `onBackPressed()` in your activity?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure what exactly to put there...

Comment: Maybe do a beginTransaction() with the name of the fragment you want to go back to?